# MS Access vba to change values in a column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to change values in a column titled "CURRENT QUARTER" from .NULL. to "2017 Q2" the number of values is very large so I am trying to more than 10,000 so need to do it via a macro. Any one knows how to do this? I only have experience on VBA in excel

Comment: This sounds like a simple update query

Comment: A simple update query on the table - remember to check that the record `IS NULL` before updating the value (if all records are null then no need to check that).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a saved update query and run it. Or:

```
Dim sqltext as string  
sqltext = "Update tablename SET [CURRENT QUARTER] = " & chr(34) & 2017 Q2 &chr(34) & "WHERE [CURRENT QUARTER] Is Null;"  
Docmd.RunSql sqltext
```

Replace tablename with the name of your table.